# Intermittent issues connecting with cqlsh to nodes running on Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

I'm having some issues with my authentication when trying to login with cqlsh. I'm running a cluster of 3 nodes that is spaced out on three different physical nodes in Kubernetes. It has been rolling like a charm for the last month but around a week or so, it started to go down. Down below you can see when I try to login to the different nodes and the responses. (a FYI it's not always node 0 that has problem, I've also seen node 1 has the same problem but then node 0 worked fine. This question seems similar to [Cassandra PasswordAuthenticator causing timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907248/cassandra-passwordauthenticator-causing-timeout) but the suggestion there did not help.

```
I have no name!@cassandra-0:/$ cqlsh -u cassandra -p abc123
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',)}) 

I have no name!@cassandra-1:/$ cqlsh -u cassandra -p abc123
Python 2.7 support is deprecated. Install Python 3.6+ or set CQLSH_NO_WARN_PY2 to suppress this message.Connected to mycluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>

I have no name!@cassandra-2:/$ cqlsh -u cassandra -p abc123
Python 2.7 support is deprecated. Install Python 3.6+ or set CQLSH_NO_WARN_PY2 to suppress this message.Connected to mycluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

Here is the logs from node 0

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 MessagingMetrics.java:206 - HINT_RSP messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 4 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 8582 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 MessagingMetrics.java:206 - HINT_REQ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 2 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 8582 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 StatusLogger.java:65 - Pool Name                       Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 StatusLogger.java:69 - ReadStage                            0         0          17086         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 StatusLogger.java:69 - CompactionExecutor                   0         0         195522         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,090 StatusLogger.java:69 - MutationStage                        0         0          88515         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - MemtableReclaimMemory                0         0            210         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - PendingRangeCalculator               0         0             13         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - GossipStage                          0         0         660680         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - SecondaryIndexManagement             0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - HintsDispatcher                      2         0          37776         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - Repair-Task                          0         0              5         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - Native-Transport-Requests            0         0          17111         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - RequestResponseStage                 0         0             20         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - MemtableFlushWriter                  0         0            210         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0         0         0            210         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - MemtablePostFlush                    0         0            255         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - Sampler                              0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - ValidationExecutor                   0         0             41         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - ViewBuildExecutor                    0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,091 StatusLogger.java:69 - InternalResponseStage                0         0         151676         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:69 - AntiEntropyStage                     0         0            249         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:69 - CacheCleanupExecutor                 0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:79 - CompactionManager                 0         0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:91 - MessagingService                n/a       0/0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:101 - Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:103 - KeyCache                      11452                 75497472                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:109 - RowCache                          0                        0                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:116 - Table                       Memtable ops,data
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,092 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.columns                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.types                       0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.indexes                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.keyspaces                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.aggregates                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.triggers                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.tables                      0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.views                       0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_schema.functions                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.compaction_history               3,634
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.IndexInfo                          0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.repairs                            0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.size_estimates           49344,1087744
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.table_estimates          98688,2339296
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.paxos                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.built_views                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.peer_events                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.peers_v2                           0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.peers                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.peer_events_v2                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.batches                            0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,093 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.transferred_ranges                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.transferred_ranges_v2                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.view_builds_in_progress                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.local                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.sstable_activity              229,2816
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.available_ranges_v2                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.available_ranges                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,094 StatusLogger.java:119 - system.prepared_statements                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,095 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_auth.roles                         0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,095 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_auth.role_members                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,095 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,095 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_auth.network_permissions                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,095 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_auth.role_permissions                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,100 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_distributed.parent_repair_history           10,418916
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,100 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_distributed.repair_history         29495,15967
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,100 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_distributed.view_build_status                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,101 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_traces.sessions                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2022-10-26 17:39:00,101 StatusLogger.java:119 - system_traces.events                      0,0
```

The keyspace replication

```
cassandra@cqlsh> describe keyspace system_auth;
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 
'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '3'} AND durable_writes = true;
```

Nodetool status

```
I have no name!@cassandra-prod-2:/$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load      Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  10.233.92.33   3.63 MiB  256     100.0%            xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1
UN  10.233.96.184  4.2 MiB   256     100.0%            xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1
UN  10.233.90.48   3.24 MiB  256     100.0%            xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1
```

I've tried to do nodetool repair without success.

Does anyone have a clue whats going on?

I've tried to restart all the c*-nodes, the underlying nodes in the k8-cluster, ran nodetool repair but without success.

Comment: can you share `nodetool status` from c0 node.

Comment: also, try to login  with IP
`cqlsh 10.233.92.33 9042 -u your_username -p your_password`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. But don't be concerned, I'm just letting you know for future reference. Cheers! 

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The nodetool yield the same on c0 as c2 unfortunately. I tested with the ip/port but no luck there neither. However, I could login to c1 in c0s pod but could not login to c0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptom you described where sometimes you can't connect to the cluster with cqlsh isn't so much an authentication problem but that sometimes the nodes are unresponsive.

From the log entries you posted, it shows that the node is dropping hint messages. If you recall, coordinators (which are responsible for coordinating write requests by sending mutations to all replicas) store "hints" when a replica doesn't acknowledge the write within `write_request_timeout_in_ms`.

A "hint" contains the IP of the replica that missed the write plus the mutation payload. When the replica is back online, the coordinator "replays" the mutation to the replica from the hint (known as hinted-handoff in Cassandra).

Dropped messages are a symptom of a bigger problem. Nodes drop messages because they are overloaded and it's a mechanism for load-shedding when it can't take any more requests.

Look for GC pauses which are another symptom of overload. If the pods are constrained for resources, consider allocating more RAM so you can bump up the heap size. Additionally, you can increase the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes (pods). Cheers!

Comment: What an excellent response! It's super weird since I checked all of our K8-nodes and it seemed like they did not needed more RAM, but when gave them more it seems like it fixed the problem (love the fact that more RAM/vCPU fixes problem :)). I also check the logs for GC-problem but that seemed like it was not the problem. I appreciate your comment on this. Cheers!